# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.67.dylib

Tags: node.js

I had this error when trying to commit.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.67.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
.husky/pre-commit: line 4: 20559 Abort trap: 6           yarn lint-staged
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 134 (error)
```

It seems to be coming from node and its icu4c dependency

Comment: I migrated my old mac to a new one and faced the same error in the Rails app. Found out that the node setup was missing, solved by simply installing it using brew.

Comment: I ran into this issue after upgrading from Mojave to Monterey (although it was /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib).  In addition to the answers here I somehow had a bad Node install lying around and had to `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/node\@12` then `brew install node` and now things are back to normal.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I just needed to do `brew reinstall icu4c`, see https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded

Comment: "Just ..." seems somewhat understated about a command that ran for over ten minutes and appeared to download a significant proportion of the Internet. It did, however, fix the problem, scary though it was to watch it do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just try uninstalling node and icu4c e reinstalling (clean) again.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: In fact it doesn't solve an "immediate" problem, original question was 19 months old. **My answer is really intended to be useful for the future**. Any answer given here (and also in all the others) should be understood as a "continuation" of the question: that is, one reads first the question and then the answers given, connecting them. In the question, for example, it says that the problems seem to arise from the node and icu4c packages. My answer mentions both, and is thus a continuation in the question/discussion.
Reading only the answers, in fact, no discussion would make sense.

Comment: I think @Tyler2P is just asking for a little more explanation for what you're doing or why, if possible. Unfortunately, it follows a trend I've been seeing of burying this simple request deep inside a paragraph with so many unnecessary and kindly worded sentences that it sounds condescending. It's like people are getting paid by the character........

Answer (score 0):

In case there are others out there with the same sub issue:

If you need an outdated version of node (like node 14 now) brew won't let you install it, but you can use nvm

In that case you would do:

```
nvm uninstall node@14
nvm reinstall node@14
```